# To what extent is the generation of the product sigma-algebra by cylinder sets necessary for probability theory?

Tags: probability-theory

I was reading about the product of an infinite number of probability spaces 
$(S_1,E_1,P_1) \otimes (S_2,E_2,P_2) \ \otimes \cdots$

where each $S_i$ is a sample space, $E_i$ an event algebra, and $P_i$ a probability measure.

- Jordan Bell, [Infinite product measures](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/29be/6b90464479b6057609e9340264d59013d901.pdf)

The event algebra for the product is defined as the sigma algebra generated by all of the 'cylinder sets', which are cartesian products $e_1 \times e_2 \times \cdots$ where $e_i$ differs from $S_i$ for only a finite set of indices $i$.

It does look like a plausible restriction.  For one thing it has the advantage that the probability of a cylinder set is well defined, as it only involves taking a finite product.   And it flows naturally from the parsimonious requirement that the projection functions be measurable functions.   So it sounds like the right product from a categorical standpoint.

But I'm curious to know to what extent is this restriction *necessary*?  (Leaving aside questions of elegance.)

For concreteness, take a coin flipping experiment, that goes on forever...

Consider the "outcome" in which heads comes up forever.  This would be designated by the singleton event {H} x {H} x ...

But it is barred from consideration as an event, so no probability gets assigned to it.

On the one hand, as such an event could never occur in practice, from an empirical standpoint, nothing is lost by excluding it from the domain of the probability measure.

On the other hand, in the mind's eye, it still *looks* like an event, which would naturally have zero probability of occurring.

So my question is:  would something go wrong if we extended the event algebra and probability measure to include such events?

Would there be inconsistencies or paradoxes that would arise, preventing the definition of a consistent extension of the measure beyond the sigma algebra generated by the cylinder sets?

Or would there be too many possible extensions, with no definite way to identify *the* appropriate probability measure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a countable product of measure spaces you can drop the restriction that all but finitely many of the sets $e_i$ are the whole measure space $S_i$, and you get the same sigma-algebra.  This is easy to show because the set

$$e_1\times e_2 \times e_3 \times\cdots$$

is a countable intersection of cylinder sets of the form

$$ e_1 \times e_2 \times \cdots \times e_n \times S_{n+1} \times S_{n+2} \times \cdots $$

So, nothing goes wrong if you include these infinite products

$$ e_1 \times e_2 \times e_3 \times \cdots$$

in your sigma-algebra when defining a countably infinite product of probability measure spaces: they are already present in the usual theory.